# Graphite Source of Unknown Metrics

Tags: graphite

I'm getting an "unknown" metric - in that I didn't request the metric directly. I've deleted them from storage but it is immediately recreated. I figure this means they it is being generated by some automatic process but I can't tell how.

I deleted the metric on the 8th and the 16th and you can see where they are being created after the fact:

```
/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/archive/creates.log-20161208:08/12/2016 15:28:37 :: new metric whz:-u.count matched schema default
/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/archive/creates.log-20161208:08/12/2016 15:28:37 :: new metric whz:-u.count matched aggregation schema default
/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/archive/creates.log-20161208:08/12/2016 15:28:37 :: creating database file /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/whz:-u/count.wsp (archive=[(60, 10080)] xff=None agg=None)
/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/archive/creates.log-20161216:16/12/2016 14:36:38 :: new metric whz:-u.count matched schema default
/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/archive/creates.log-20161216:16/12/2016 14:36:38 :: new metric whz:-u.count matched aggregation schema default
/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/archive/creates.log-20161216:16/12/2016 14:36:38 :: creating database file /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/whz:-u/count.wsp (archive=[(60, 10080)] xff=None agg=None)
```

I've done a recursive grep of /opt/graphite for whz and all I get back is the logs so I assume it's not set somewhere in the configuration.

**How can I determine the source of this metric?**